# Laravel application deployed to AWS Elastic Beanstalk shows file not found error

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, laravel-storage

I'm using AWS EB to host my Laravel 5.8 application. I have a view where I upload files. These files are 2 CSV files and a ZIP archive. Long story short, these files are stored locally to process their content, once they are stored, their stored location, which is returned as `temp/...` is concatenated with the helper method `storage_path()` to determine the full path for the file to open for processing:

```
$file = file(storage_path() . '\app/' . $filePath);
```

Once this line is reached, I'm getting this error:

```
fopen(/var/app/current/storage\app/temp/routes/20190906143753/ztySdkFwY5bAvQhIK4Mlsftz8fzVJfPK3S3d5CSV.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

*************** **UPDATE** ***************

So it turns out that the storage folder in my Laravel project had no write permission. I've managed to fix that and now the files are actually being stored. However, another problem showed up. Which is files aren't stored fully until the execution of the page ends, which is not what I want since those files are also used during the same process for other purposes.

Comment: Have you connected to the EC2 server over SSH to verify that is the correct path to the file?

Comment: @MarkB yes I did, and the files aren't stored. I don't know why.

Comment: @MarkB Hey, I've been missing around with this and I found out that the `storage` folder didn't have the permissions necessary to store the files. Now I can see that the files are being stored, however I can only see the files when my Laravel script ends. While I require reading the files during the script execution.